# Transaction Fees

Tags: transaction-fees

Good morning, 
I was reading the wiki on transaction fees and it says a transaction of < 1000 bytes is sent without fees. Although after stumbling in bitxoinsfees i read that

> If this size is less than 10,000 bytes and step 3 found that the
>   transaction's priority was high enough to qualify as free, then the
>   transaction still qualifies as free, otherwise a fee is required.

So which of the 2 is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Sending) says (and you can probably trust this wiki):

> A transaction may be safely sent without fees if these conditions are met:
>
> - It is smaller than 1,000 bytes.
> - All outputs are 0.01 BTC or larger.
> - Its priority is large enough (see the Technical Info section below)

The site you read is probably outdated, because since Bitcoin 0.8.6 is released, the amount of bytes is reduced from 10000 to 1000.

[Source](http://tradeblock.com/research/bitcoin-0-8-6-released-updates-block-size-limits-free-transactions-osx-bugs/):

> In an effort to make free transactions more commonly accessible, Bitcoin 0.8.6 lowers the maximum size of free transactions from 10,000 bytes to 1,000 bytes and eliminates the minimum 0.01 XBT output requirement

---

You can see from the answer [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9971/does-the-bitcoin-qt-client-have-a-minimum-transaction-fee), that the wiki previously stated 10000 bytes as minimum. So the official wiki is updated, the site isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In this [wiki page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees#Priority_transactions) it is said that: *Historically it was not required to include a fee for every transaction* **however** *today miners choose which transactions to mine only based on fee-rate.*.